# How do I set Jackson's constructorDetector with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to configure Jackson so that it automatically deserializes using constructors, without needing annotations. With Spring Boot, this works out of the box for most constructors but not single argument constructors.

Jackson 2.12 has released a configuration option to enable deserialization for single argument constructors as well:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .constructorDetector(ConstructorDetector.USE_PROPERTIES_BASED)
    .build()
```

However, this doesn't use the usual Feature enabling/disabling interface. How can I set this with Spring Boot?

1. I don't want to lose any Spring Boot autoconfiguration that is being applied to the ObjectMapper bean.
2. I can't define a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean because, as of Spring Boot 2.4.1, this has not yet been updated to allow constructorDetector to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a bean of either `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` or `ObjectMapper` will prevent application of any auto-configuration for these beans, [as documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

Instead, you can define a bean of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` which is a lambda that lets you call additional methods on the Spring Boot auto-configured `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`.

Additionally, `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` has the method `postConfigurer` which is another call back which lets you call methods on the auto-configured `ObjectMapper`.

Putting these together:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder.postConfigurer(mapper ->
            mapper.setConstructorDetector(USE_PROPERTIES_BASED)
    );
}
```